# How to use pluck to get attribute from model associated with class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Entry model which belongs to an Organization model...twice.

```rb
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :temp_organization, class_name: "Organization"
end
```

I'm trying to write a single AR query that pulls off the associated organization and temp_organization name using `pluck`.

```rb
Entry
  .includes(:organization, :temp_organization)
  .pluck('organizations.name', 'temp_organizations.name')
```

This crashes with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause  entry for table "temp_organizations"
```

Which makes sense - there is no `temp_organizations` table since that association is managed through the regular `organizations` table.

How do I get `pluck` to pull the temp_organization name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with multiple joins to the same table, AR does some magic and renames the table, which is why you can't pull up the right table name.

You can check what the table name is by looking at the generated sql:

```
Entry.includes(:organization, :temp_organization).to_sql
```

You should get something like:

```
...INNER JOIN \"organizations\" \"entries_temp_organizations\" ON \"entries_temp_organizations\"...
```

I would suspect the table name is 'entries_temp_organizations' (following AR rule of alphabetical ordering for join tables).  A pluck with the correct table name should do the trick.

Comment: When I execute `Entry....to_sql`, it triggers three DB queries, `"SELECT \"entries\".* FROM \"entries\""`, `SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = 1` and `SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" IN (52...`.  However, if I change the `includes` to `joins`, I do get a single SELECT statement that looks more like what you're expecting.  It shows the table name to be `temp_organizations_entries`.  However, it's still generating that same error when I use includes or joins).

Comment: I must have had an error in my code somewhere.  Everything is working now when I used `temp_organizations_entries.name`.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Try using,

```
Entry
  .includes(:organization, :temp_organization)
  .references(:organization, :temp_organization)
  .pluck('organizations.name', 'entries_temp_organizations.name')
```

Comment: No luck, I still get the same error (except the table name changes to `temp_organizations_entries`).

Comment: @CodeSmith what's the name of the table of `Entry` model ?

Comment: @CodeSmith Also, what's the table name of `organization` model ?

Comment: entries and organizations.

Comment: @CodeSmith Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the code work using `temp_organizations_entries.name`.  I didn't know about the `references` method before; very useful. It turns out my specific query is working without using `references`, but it's good know it's available.